# GIven an Image crop of vehicle how to find the colour of the vehicle with image processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, image-segmentation

Giving below a method I have used for getting the dominant colour. I want to know which is that colour. So, do anyone has a better solution than this or any other way to modify it. It would be great if someone helps with some snippets of code.

```
from PIL import Image


def get_dominant_color(pil_img, palette_size=16):
    # Resize image to speed up processing
    img = pil_img.copy()
    img.thumbnail((100, 100))

    # Reduce colors (uses k-means internally)
    paletted = img.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=palette_size)

    # Find the color that occurs most often
    palette = paletted.getpalette()
    color_counts = sorted(paletted.getcolors(), reverse=True)
    palette_index = color_counts[0][1]
    dominant_color = palette[palette_index*3:palette_index*3+3]

return dominant_color

im = Image.open('sb.png')
result = get_dominant_color(im)
print(result)
```

Comment: You have a function that returns the dominant color. What more do you want ?

Comment: What is the name of color, should I use HSV or how to do that?

Comment: Name based on which color chart ?

Comment: You can use a colour chart and find the closest distance from your colour to any one of these and find the name: https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_nbs.asp.  The distance metric is subject to debate.  Just using the distance in raw RGB does not capture perceptual differences well.  You may need to use another colour space to properly capture distances, like CIELAB.